# Angular 7 cli not reading custom ts file

Tags: angular, typescript, interface, angular7

I am trying to read a custom file in angular 7 component but it is getting failed when server is restarting while there is no error in the component ts file.

**ERROR:**

> app/zontify-components/zontify-dynamic-field.directive.ts(5,29): error
>   TS2306: File
>   'D:/Phython/zontify/Purchased/webmin/angular-7/src/src/app/field-interface.ts'
>   is not a module.
>   app/zontify-components/zontify-select/zontify-select.component.ts(3,29):
>   error TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/app/field-interface'.
>   app/zontify-lead/zontify-lead.component.ts(10,29): error TS2306: File
>   'D:/Phython/zontify/Purchased/webmin/angular-7/src/src/app/field-interface.ts'
>   is not a module.

Please let me know what is wrong I am doing? I am new to angular 7.

Interface directory :

> Project > app > field-interface.ts

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution... We need to use the relative path to the file rather than the absolute path...